# Will a json-encoced avro, generated by org.apache.avro.io.JsonEncoder, break if I convert the returned bytearray to a string?

Tags: avro

To my understanding in order to convert a record to a json-encoded avro in java we need to do the following:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, outputStream);
    DatumWriter<MyRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    writer.write(user, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
```

I want to save this to a file. Is there a chance that I will break the message if I convert it to string? e.g. with `outputStream.toString()`.
In other words can a json-encoded avro be treated as text?